# Report Contact with Opportunity, show Contact only once

Tags: reporting, custom-report-type

I am trying to make a report that shows Contacts with at least 1 Opportunity.  I have accomplished this, however, I only want to see the contact listed once but also not grouped (like in photo)[image].

Ideally, I'd like to just see the Contact Name and that date field just once and not for every opportunity.

Edit: The date field is related to the Contact and has nothing to do with the Opportunity record

Comment: What Date field are you showing? If the Opportunity Close Date, and a Contact has more than one Opportunity, which record's Date do you want to show?

Comment: updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should apply a [Cross Filter](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=reports_cross_filters_create.htm&type=5) for "Contacts with Opportunities". Do this in a Contacts report rather than a Contacts and Opportunities report.

This will allow you to report at the Contact level, applying a filter based on Opportunities without including Opportunity data in the report body.